# Informatica Installation Issue

Tags: windows-10, extract, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

In Windows 10 while proceeding for installation of Informatica I connected through SQL Plus where I need to create a user for which I used below command.

create user as info identified by inf;

I am getting below error:

ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name

Comment: Now it is resolved, facing issue of Connection connectivity on Windows 10 after selecting JDBC details as below:
Database Address: localhost:1521
Database Service Name:orcl

Database UserID: c##scott

Comment: Issue resolved ? I think informatica normally uses ODBC for database connections. So, you can set it up easily to connect to ant DB.